# Angularjs with Material design md-menu-item Vertical issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am creating menu as per the demo of the angularjs material. In the demo menu is coming vertical as it is dynamic. But the same menu if I create manually then it is creating horizontal.

[image]

My some code

```
<md-toolbar>
                    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                        <md-menu md-position-mode="target-left bottom"  md-offset="-22 6">
                            <md-button aria-label="Plan & Book" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                                Parent Item 1
                            </md-button>
                            <md-menu-content width="4">
                                <md-menu-item>
                                    <md-button>Item 1</md-button>
                                    <md-button>Item 2</md-button>
                                    <md-button>Item 3</md-button>
                                </md-menu-item>
                            </md-menu-content>
                        </md-menu>
                        <md-menu>
                            <md-button aria-label="Manage A Booking" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                                Parent Item 2
                            </md-button>
                            <md-menu-content class="dropdown">
                            </md-menu-content>
                        </md-menu>
                    </div>
                </md-toolbar>
```

My full code pen
http://codepen.io/milindsaraswala/pen/dXvVOa

How can I make it vertical menu !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to separate the `<md-menu-item>`:

```
<md-menu-item>
    <md-button>Item 1</md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item>
    <md-button>Item 2</md-button>
</md-menu-item>
<md-menu-item>
    <md-button>Item 3</md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

Your code updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/beqaqZ